# Configure one app to be built using two Android name spaces?

Tags: android

I have an app that, for release, needs building as two apps. The app will self-reconfigure based on the app's namespace, so I just need to build two versions, each with its own slightly different namespace.

I obviously want to avoid changing source code package names, and would like to change the name space in one place so building either version is quick and easy.

Can I simply change the package name in the <manifest> tag in the Android manifest, making sure my references are fully qualified? Are there any gotchas with doing this?

Comment: Are you using a custom application class and is this the only difference in the Manifest? no different icons either?

Comment: I am using a custom application class, the same for both apps so easy to split if needed. The icons are the same, as is everything else, I just need two apps with diff namespaces (they use that namespace name to change the functionality).

Comment: OK, so I've tried doing this to see what happens, and the app is failing to build as the change to the manifest package name has caused the R resources class to move to the new package, which means all my references to R.* across the app are not found. Is it possible to specify the package to hold the resources, separately from the package name for the app itself?

Comment: You just add `import com.mycompany.myproject.mylibrary.R` where needed.

Comment: That works for that package, but on switching it back in the manifest (to build the other version) all the import statements need changing. I can't import both in parallel as one will not exist. I cannot do a * import, as there are conflicts. How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two separate application projects, with separate package names, and have the common functionality - the bulk of your code - in a shared library project.

Comment: This would take a substantial effort, so I know this will work, but I suspect I can create the two APKs without needing to break up the project.

Comment: Actually it's really easy to convert your main app project into a library project. Then all you need to have is two app projects, one for each package name, which contain nothing more than the manifest.

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse, so how easy it is is an unknown. If I don't need to do this, I'd rather not waste time on it.

Comment: This is the standard way to go and exactly what I would suggest. You shouldn't have to change R as the Library project's package can stay as the original package.

Comment: I did move to a library project. It is simple, but took a few hours to get everything to build and execute correctly.